# Populate ComboBox2 depending on Combobox1 selected item

Tags: c#

i am a student, and a newbie to programming, i have two comboboxes, combobox1 and combobox2 combobox1 contains mobile company's like nokia,samsung,htc and combobox2 contains mobile models like samsung,s3 and etc, i want to sort the two combobox i mean when i click the nokia in the combobox1 then all the model of nokia should be visible in the list of combobo2, so i have decided to used foreign key relationship

```
          Manufacturer -table
        - manufacturerid (primary key)
        - name

         Model -table
        - modelid (primary key)
        - manufacturerid (foreign key to manufacturer)
         - name
```

Example for the data:

Manufacturer table

```
         manufacturerid name
     -------------- ----------
    1              Nokia
    2              Samsung
    3              HTC
```

Model table

```
       modelid manufacturerid name
     ------- -------------- ----------
     1       1              C7
     2       1              Lumia 900
     3       1              Lumia 920
     4       2              Galaxy S II
     5       2              Galaxy S III
     6       3              Desire X
     7       3              Windows Phone 8X
     8       3              One S
```

i want that if i select nokia in the first combobox then the second combobox will select all the models which are manufactureid = 1
what to use? how can i do that?
priviously i was using

```
 private void comboBox4_SelectedIndexChanged(object sender, EventArgs e)
  {
     comboBox3.Text = "";
   if ("samsung" == comboBox4.SelectedItem.ToString())
      {
           comboBox3.DataSource = table1BindingSource;
           comboBox3.ValueMember = "samsung";
           comboBox3.DisplayMember = "samsung";
      }
   if ("htc" == comboBox4.SelectedItem.ToString())
      {
         comboBox3.DataSource = table1BindingSource;
         comboBox3.ValueMember = "htc";
          comboBox3.DisplayMember = "htc";
       }
  }
```

but i have to update the samsung string each time i add a new model, so i decided to work with tables so that i can update that

Comment: the above examples i used the whole column for one company but there was some problem so i dec ided to work with this foreign key

Comment: pls have look at my answer

Comment: You want to populate combobox or you want to update ??

Comment: what exactly you want? it seems the code you are trying will work fine.. Do you want to optimize the code?

Comment: i want to pupolate with correct model

Comment: mr grenn yess the code works but when i have the three columns one for htc another for nokia and third one for htc in the same table. when i fill the 15 values in htc and nokia column and in combobox1 selects samsung then in combobox2 has 15 null values which is the drawback so i decided to use foreign key

Answer (score 2, accepted):

On 1st combobox `SelectedIndexChanged` event (manufacture combobox)
fetch select `manufacturerid`
and then fire this query to populate other combobox ie (model)

`Select modelid,name from modeltable where manufactuerid=@combox1Value`

**Code Behind** 
Something Like this, i just wrote this code without IDE have a look, might be need some modification

```
private void monufactureComobobox_SelectedIndexChanged(object sender, EventArgs e)
{

 string fecthManufacturerID= manufactureComobobox.selectedItem;
 DataTable dtModel = new DataTable();
 dtModel= ModelComboPopulate(fecthManufacturerID);
 ModelcomboBox.DataSource = dtModel;
 ModelcomboBox.ValueMember = "modelid";
 ModelcomboBox.DisplayMember = "name";

}

public DataTable ModelComboPopulate(string ID)
{
 DataSet ds = new DataSet();
 using (SqlConnection con = new SqlConnection(connection))
 {
    string myquery="Select modelid,name from modeltable where manufacturerid=@combox1Value";
    SqlCommand cmd = new SqlCommand(myquery, con);
    SqlDataAdapter dap = new SqlDataAdapter();
    dap.SelectCommand = cmd;
    cmd.Parameters.Add("@combox1Value", SqlDbType.NVarChar, 15).Value = ID;
    dap.Fill(ds);
    return ds.Tables[0];
  }

}
```

Comment: paaji, i have to directly write this?
private void comboBox4_SelectedIndexChanged(object sender, EventArgs e)
  {  Select modelid,name from modeltable where manufactuerid=@combox1Value
}

Comment: @shariq_khan: Bhai, you want to populate combobox or you want to update the data ?

Comment: paaji i want to populate the combobox. when combobox1 nokia is selected then all the nokia model with manufacturer id 1 will populate in the combobox2. like that way

Comment: Since 'WindowsFormsApplication2.Form6.comboBox6_SelectedIndexChanged(object, System.EventArgs)' returns void, a return keyword must not be followed by an object expression what is this sir? i dont know the meaning of such error

Comment: @shariq_khan: remove this line `return ds.table[0]`

Comment: let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/21938/discussion-between-satinder-singh-and-shariq-khan)

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/14162839/how-to-transfer-the-text-from-dynamically-generated-user-control-to-a-textbox
CAN YOU HELP ME paaji PLEASE

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/14169154/getting-sum-of-text-from-all-the-dynamically-generated-control can you help here paaji this is the real one..

Answer (score 2):

Include a function to retrieve data from database as follows

```
public DataTable Select(String sqlQuery)
   {       
       con.Open();
       SqlDataAdapter adapter = new SqlDataAdapter(sqlQuery,con);
       DataTable table = new DataTable();
       adapter.Fill(table);
       con.Close();
       return table;
   }
```

and in `Page_Load` event

```
protected void Page_Load(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
   if(!Page.IsPostBack)
     {
      String sqlQuery="select manufacturerid,name From Manufacturertable";

      comboBox4.DataSource = cls.Select(sqlQuery);
      comboBox4.DataTextField = "name";
      comboBox4.DataValueField = "manufacturerid";
      comboBox4.DataBind();
   }
 }
```

and in `SelectedIndexChanged` event of `comboBox4`

```
protected void comboBox4_SelectedIndexChanged(object sender, EventArgs e) {
    String sqlQuery="select modelid,name From Modeltable where manufacturerid="+ Convert.ToInt16(comboBox4.SelectedValue.ToString());

    comboBox3.DataSource = cls.Select(sqlQuery);
    comboBox3.DataTextField = "name";
    comboBox3.DataValueField = "modelid";
    comboBox3.DataBind();
}
```

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/14162839/how-to-transfer-the-text-from-dynamically-generated-user-control-to-a-textbox
CAN YOU HELP ME BHAI PLEASE

Answer (score 2):

Use `DataSet` or `DataTable` to store the two tables and then populate the strings in a list string `strArr`. Something like below: (*Atleast the logic should work*)

```
List<string> strArr = new List<string>();
strArr.Items.Clear();
for(int intSubCount = 0; intSubCount < dtTable2.Rows.Count;intSubCount++)
{
   if(MyComboBox.Text.Equals(dtTable2.Rows[intSubCount]["modelid"].ToString()))
   {
       strArr.Add(dtTable2.Rows[intSubCount]["name"].ToString());
   }
}
//
comboBox3.DataSource = strArr;
```

**Or else**

The simple way is to use `DataView`

```
  DataView dv =  dtTable1.defaultView;
  dv.RowFilter("modelid = '" + myComboBox.Text + "'");
  //use DataView to populate the Second ComboBox.
```

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/14162839/how-to-transfer-the-text-from-dynamically-generated-user-control-to-a-textbox
CAN YOU HELP ME PLEASE